# How to remove a row from table using jquery-tabledit plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using [jquery-tabledit](http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples) plugin for editing / removing rows in table.The editing mode works fine, but doesn't work removing functionality.
Please give me some kind of information how to make to remove the row of the table.

Here is the markup.

```
<table class="table datatable table-striped table-bordered table-editable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$('#example2').Tabledit({
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [
            [1, 'nickname'],
            [2, 'firstname'],
            [3, 'lastname'],
            [4, 'lastname']
        ]
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript:

```
$('#rowID).remove();
```